# Visual Studio - Find in Files except in files with type of

Tags: visual-studio-2012, findinfiles

Visual Studio's Find in Files has the option "Look at these file types:" which allows you to specify specific file types (eg. all .aspx files).

It is possible to specify file types NOT to look at?

I need something like "search in all files and do not search in *.resx files".

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify file types NOT to look at with the Visual Studio's Find in Files.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 it is possible tough. Not in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/mj066kva7/). Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Link to screenshot in answer is dead ("postimg.org’s server IP address could not be found").

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 added this feature in "Find in Files".  Plenty out there on this.  Otherwise can look at the web blob "Modernizing Find in Files" at:
[Modernizing Find in Files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/modernizing-find-in-files/)